# htaccess rewrite rule for serving index.php from parent directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am looking for .htaccess rewrite rule that will map the following

```
GET /a/       => a/index.php
GET /a/b/     => a/b/index.php
GET /a/b/c/   => a/b/index.php
```

Basically, if an index.php file is present in a directory it should be served. If not, then it should look in the parent directory for index.php and serve that.

I'm trying to get clean URLs in PHP without having to route everything through a single index.php file.

Comment: Also routing w/ the PHP development server works this way by default.

Comment: What "PHP development server" is that? The problem with this approach is that you potentially create _duplicate content_ (multiple URLs serving the same content).

Comment: The PHP development server that ships w/ PHP... e.g., running `php -S localhost:5000` from the command line

Comment: I'm not concerned w/ duplicate content. In my case the index.php would treat the last "directory" as an argument to the script.. so "c" in  the example in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This first solution assumes the request maps to a physical directory path, eg. Where `a`, `b` and `c` in a request of the form `/a/b/c/` are all directories on the filesystem...

You don't need to use mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule`) for this. You can just specify relative `DirectoryIndex` documents. For example, to handle a directory structure 4 levels deep (ie. `/a/b/c/`):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php ../index.php ../../index.php ../../../index.php
```

If no directory index document is found then you'll get the usual 403 Forbidden (assuming directory indexes are disabled).

If you removed all `index.php` documents along the filesystem path then you'll get a 400 Bad Request if it tries to fetch an index document above the document root.

---

**UPDATE:** However, it seems that what is really required is a multi-level front controller type pattern instead, since the requested URL does not necessarily exist as a physical filesystem path. For example, given a URL of the form `/a/b/c/` then it may be that only `a` and `b` are physical directories and `c/` is just an additional URL-path that should be passed to the front-controller located at `/a/b/index.php` or `/a/index.php` or even `/index.php`, depending on which is found first.

You can do something like the following for a generic any directory level deep directory structure:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Exception - Reached the document root then stop
# (Prevents rewrite loop if index.php is missing - 404 instead)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Exception - Any request for a valid file stop here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If already requesting "index.php" then step up a directory
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?[^/]+/index\.php$ /$1index.php [L]

# Otherwise try "index.php" in the current path segment
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?[^/]*$ /$1index.php [L]
```

The optional `(.*/)?` pattern at the start of the regex is to allow drilling all the way down to the document root. If this was not made optional (and included the slash in the captured pattern) then it would stop one directory down in the document root (ie. at `/a/index.php`).

By not specifically checking that the request maps to a directory, it can call the front controller in a parent directory when it is missing from the directory being requested.

Comment: This does not work for me. It just 404s. Is there anything else that needs to be enabled for this to work?

Comment: `DirectoryIndex` is part of mod_dir, which is enabled by default. Nothing else is required. You might need to reset `DirectoryIndex` first (although unlikely), ie. `DirectoryIndex disabled`. Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Any other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: My .htaccess is in the document root and there are no other .htaccess files in sub folders. The only content in the .htaccess file is the one liner code snippet you posted.

Comment: I want the index.php to be relative to the URL path and not the document root that apache is serving content from.. meaning `GET /a/b/c` should be looking in `document_root/a/b/index.php` rather than `document_root/../../index.php`

Comment: So, even a request for `example.com/` (where `index.php` exists in the document root), results in a 404? And `example.com/a/` (where `/a/index.php` exists) results in a 404?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. In those cases it serves index.php correctly. But it does not look for ../index.php (parent folder index.php)

Comment: This is relative to the URL-path (not the document root). Is `/a/b/c/` a valid directory path? Or are you passing path-info?

Comment: This only works if the directory path you specify is a real directory path. If `c/` does not exist then you will indeed get a 404. Is that what's happening here?

Comment: I think I see what isn't working. "c" is not a folder. The urls are dynamic in my case. For instance, I want `members/index.php` to handle both these routes `/members/sally45` and  `/members/bob13/`

Comment: Ah, so, you are really after a multiple-front-controller type pattern, where the URL-path could map to a real directory path or it could be entirely virtual? I'll have to have another think on this.

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some tinkering I have a solution that seems to work. I'm basically capturing known path segments and using capture vars to map to file system relative to the document root. However, it would be ideal to have a regex that went N levels deep w/out needing multiple rewrite rules.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# 3 levels deep
# GET /a/b/c-some-thing-here    
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*) /$1/$2/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# 4 levels deep
# GET /a/b/c/d-some-thing-here
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /$1/$2/$3/index.php [L]
```

Comment: I've included a more general (N level deep) version of this [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46846479/369434).

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) ./index.php?__path__=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

index.php

```
$path = '';
if (is_array($_GET) && array_key_exists('__path__', $_GET)) {
    $path = trim($_GET['__path__']);
}
$path = trim($path, '/');
//you can use $path, path can be "a", "a/b" or "a/b/c" for your samples
```

Comment: This still routes everything though a PHP file. I want to skip any PHP logic and force everything to the index.php file.

Comment: ok, i misunderstood :( you can use angular style hashtags domain.com/#!